# JS: How to search object for presence of fields based on logical conditions in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following JS object:

```
let obj = {
    b: 1,
    c: 1,
    d: 2
}
```

I want to write a function that takes an input array and checks whether the fields listed in this array are present in `obj`, but I want to have logic in the conditions. So something like

```
arr = ['b', 'c' || 'd']   (returns true if obj has an entry for `b`, and for either `c` or `d`)
```

or

```
arr = ['c' && 'd']   (returns true only if obj has entries for both `c` and `d`)
```

so in my function I imagine writing a condition like

```
return arr.forEach(condition => object[condition])
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: `'c' || 'd'` is not "a condition in array", it's just evaluated and the result is `'c'`. The same as if you had `[1, 1+2]` which isn't a mathematical expression but just `3`.

Comment: Yep, understood. That was just an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: can you add `||` and `&&` as string elements inside those arrays to begin with and work from there?

Comment: OK, so if you're free to define the array as you want, why not just define functions? `[x => "b" in x, x => "c" in x || "d" in x]` then apply them to the object?

Comment: you are not going to have the syntax you want in an array. You are going to have some sort of rule parser

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to write yourself some sort of rules engine that is able to process logical checks. Below is a basic idea of using objects.

```js
function basicIdea(rules, obj) {

  const checksFns = {
    and: arr => arr.every(checkIt),
    or: arr => arr.some(checkIt),
  };

  const hasKey = key => key in obj;

  const checkIt = item => {
    if (typeof item === 'object') {
      const {
        op,
        checks
      } = item;

      return checksFns[op](checks);
    }

    return hasKey(item);
  }

  return checkIt(rules);
}

var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
};

console.log('check and good', basicIdea({
  op: 'and',
  checks: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}, obj1));

console.log('check and bad', basicIdea({
  op: 'and',
  checks: ['a', 'b', 'd']
}, obj1));

console.log('check or good', basicIdea({
  op: 'or',
  checks: ['d', 'a']
}, obj1));

console.log('check or bad', basicIdea({
  op: 'or',
  checks: ['d', 'e']
}, obj1));

console.log('check and or good', basicIdea({
    op: 'and',
    checks: ['a', {
      op: 'or',
      checks: [
        'b',
        'c'
      ]
    }],
  },
  obj1));
  
  console.log('check and or bad', basicIdea({
    op: 'and',
    checks: ['a', {
      op: 'or',
      checks: [
        'd',
        'e'
      ]
    }],
  },
  obj1));
```

Comment: I like this basic idea. I'd probably extend it to allow different operators where one is the `hasKey` but others are `or` and `and`. Then you can build up the entire ruleset in some configuration that is loaded later. E.g., in a .json file or get it from a network call, etc. Allowing more dynamic rule configuration without requiring a full rebuild of the program. Only new rule operators will need a new release then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
Write a finction like the checkFields function takes in the object, and a string representing the condition you want to check for example: "a||b" or "a&&b" or "a",
it's gonna split the string by || and && and check for the conditions and return true/false based on wether the condition istrue or not.
Next the calcResult function will take an array like ["a||b", "a"] and pass each of the items of it to the checkFields function and return true if all of the results are true.

```js
const checkFields = (obj, condition) => {
  let result = false;
  if (condition.includes("||")) {
    const [field1, field2] = condition.split("||");
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(field1) || obj.hasOwnProperty(field2)) {
      result = true;
    } else result = false;
  } else if (condition.includes("&&")) {
    const [field1, field2] = condition.split("&&");
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(field1) && obj.hasOwnProperty(field2)) {
      result = true;
    } else result = false;
  } else {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(condition)) {
      result = true;
    } else result = false;
  }

  return result;
};


const obj = {
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
  d: 2
};

const arr1 = ['b', 'c', 'd||b', 'a||f'];
const arr2 = ['b', 'c&&b', 'd&&b', 'a||d'];
const calcResult = (array) => array.reduce((acc, item) => acc && checkFields(obj, item), true);


console.log(calcResult(arr1));
console.log(calcResult(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Build up rules programmatically and evaluate them.

```js
/* library code */
const hasProp = prop => obj =>
  prop in obj;
  
const or = (...conditions) => obj =>
  conditions.some(condition => condition(obj));

const and = (...conditions) => obj =>
  conditions.every(condition => condition(obj));
  
const apply = rules => obj =>
  rules.map(fn => fn(obj));
/* /library code */

const arr = [
  hasProp("a"), // false
  hasProp("b"), // true
  or(hasProp("a"), hasProp("b")), // true
  or(hasProp("a"), hasProp("z")), // false
  and(hasProp("c"), hasProp("d")), // true
  and(hasProp("a"), hasProp("d")), // false
  and(hasProp("b"), hasProp("c"), hasProp("d")), // true
  and(or(hasProp("a"), hasProp("b")), and(hasProp("d"), hasProp("d"))) // true
];

const checkAllRules = apply(arr);

console.log(checkAllRules(obj));
```

```html
<script>
//set up data
let obj = {
    b: 1,
    c: 1,
    d: 2
}
</script>
```

This can be extended with any amount of more checks (like if a property has a specific value, if it is a Date object) and operators (like `not` to invert a result):

```js
/* library code */
const hasProp = prop => obj =>
  prop in obj;
  
const hasValue = (prop, value) => obj =>
  obj[prop] === value;

const isDateObject = obj =>
  obj instanceof Date;
  
const or = (...conditions) => obj =>
  conditions.some(condition => condition(obj));

const and = (...conditions) => obj =>
  conditions.every(condition => condition(obj));

const not = rule => obj => 
  !rule(obj);
  
const apply = rules => obj =>
  rules.map(fn => fn(obj));
/* /library code */

const arr = [
  hasValue("b", 1), // true
  hasValue("b", 7), // false
  isDateObject, //false
  not(hasProp("a")), //true
  or(hasValue("b", 7), hasValue("d", 2)), // true
  and(hasValue("c", 1), not(isDateObject)), // true
];

const checkAllRules = apply(arr);

console.log(checkAllRules(obj));
```

```html
<script>
//set up data
let obj = {
    b: 1,
    c: 1,
    d: 2
}
</script>
```